# Using the binomial expansion to solve a summation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have to evaluate a summation from k=1 to n of k3^k(nCk) by setting x equal to the appropriate values in the binomial expansion.

Comment: Well... have you tried doing that?

Comment: I don't know how to do that or I would have tried. How do I start?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. So our sum has shape 
$$3n\sum  \binom{n-1}{k-1}3^{k-1}.$$
The sum $\sum  \binom{n-1}{k-1}3^{k-1}$ is closely related to the binomial expansion of $(1+3)^{n-1}$.